# How to assign value from string properties to properties object

Tags: c#

I have 2 properties

```
   public MeasureDiameterMethodEnt PrimaryCalcMethod { get; set; }
   public MeasureDiameterMethodEnt SecondaryCalcMethod { get; set; }
```

and properties with two values (PrimaryCalcMethod , SecondaryCalcMethod ) value from the database.

```
public string CalcMethodName { get; set; }
```

How to assign the value "PrimaryCalcMethod" from string properties CalcMethodName to properties object PrimaryCalcMethod?
How to assign the value "SecondaryCalcMethod" from string properties CalcMethodName to properties object SecondaryCalcMethod?

Comment: How are you storing `MeasureDiameterMethodEnt` as string/varchar on your db? Json? XML? You should do the reverse action of however you're serializing your object.

Comment: We need more information.  Are you saying you have in the string the name of a method, and you want to assign a reference to the method with that name to PrimaryCalcMethod?